# Why do Three.js trackball controls freeze if camera.position === controls.target?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working on a Three.js scene with Trackball controls in which I programmatically move the camera, and I've noticed that if I set the `camera.position` and the `controls.target` to identical values, the controls totally freeze and users can no longer zoom/pan, etc. [[codepen](https://codepen.io/duhaime/pen/zPLmQX)]:

```js
// Create the scene and a camera to view it
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

/**
* Camera
**/

// Specify the portion of the scene visiable at any time (in degrees)
var fieldOfView = 75;

// Specify the camera's aspect ratio
var aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

// Specify the near and far clipping planes. Only objects
// between those planes will be rendered in the scene
// (these values help control the number of items rendered
// at any given time)
var nearPlane = 0.1;
var farPlane = 1000;

// Use the values specified above to create a camera
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  fieldOfView, aspectRatio, nearPlane, farPlane
);

// Finally, set the camera's position in the z-dimension
camera.position.z = 5;

/**
* Renderer
**/

// Create the canvas with a renderer
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

// Specify the size of the canvas
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

// Add the canvas to the DOM
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

/**
* Controls
**/

var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

setTimeout(function() {
  controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1)
  camera.position.set(1, 1, 1)
  alert('freeze!')
}, 2500)

/**
* Cube
**/

// Create a cube with width, height, and depth set to 1
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );

// Use a simple material with a specified hex color
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffff00 });

// Combine the geometry and material into a mesh
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

// Add the mesh to our scene
scene.add( cube );

/**
* Render!
**/

function animate() {
requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
  controls.update();
}
animate();
```

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: black;
*
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/88/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/duhaime/blog/tsne-webgl/assets/js/trackball-controls.js"></script>
```

To resolve the problem, I can set the `camera.position` and `controls.target` to slightly different values, but I'd like to understand just why the controls freeze when those values are set identically.

Does anyone know what might cause the controls to freeze in this case? I'd be very grateful for any advice others have on this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into the source code of `THREE.TrackballControls()`, for example [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/84c0b9fb1726329c001cbfcf93589478026d2d03/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js#L165), then you'll notice that the internal variable `_eye` will have coordinates `[0, 0, 0]` and its length will be `0`, when you set position of your camera and control's target to the same coordinates.

This leads to that all cross-products with `_eye` will produce a vector of `[0, 0, 0]` with zero length. Actually, all calculations (`cross()`, `.crossVectors()`, `.setFromAxisAndAngle()`) with this variable will have a result of zero vector, or zero length, or zero quaternion. Thus, no pan, no zoom, no rotation.

P.S. Maybe greater specialists will add more information or even correct me, if I'm wrong )